# Why does AWS always tell me that my rate limit is exceeded for EC2 calls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codebuild

I was trying to build an AWS CodeBuild project, and the build was stuck in Queued.
After I stopped and restarted the build, it then failed in the Queued state, saying something about Client Error EC2 RateLimitExceeded.

I tried deleting the project and recreating it, and my Cloudformation template failed to create my CodeBuild project for a similar reason. It is saying that it cannot call describe-security-groups because the EC2 rate limit is exceeded.

Finally, I tried calling that same API from my command line on my own computer, and I got the same error.

I went and looked up the rate limiting rules around EC2 only to discover that it makes even less sense now, because the rules appear to be 50 maximum calls, with 10 restored per second: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/throttling.html#throttling-limits-rate-based.

The account I am working in has almost nothing running in it, and especially nothing which is calling the EC2 API, and there isn't anything running in my local which could be calling that API so much.

And so I'm wondering, why am I being told that I'm exceeding the rate limit? If there is a real reason as to why this is happening, how can I debug it?

Comment: Could be that the connections aren't closing on aws side so it keeps it at a top rate limit, have you tried contacting their support? I would ssh into the box and check whats connected to it as a recommendation

Comment: This is because there is currently a partial outage in us-east-1: https://status.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: @jordanm Ah, a partial outage would explain things. I didn't think to check that. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: @Tyler this wasted about 3 hours of my day trying to figure out as well